# Finding a function within a dynamical system using a lyapunov function

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the system for $(x_1(t),x_2(t))$

\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2\\
\dot{x}_2 &= x_1^2+u
\end{align}

Find a function $u=\phi(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ so that if

$$V(x) = \frac12(x_1^2+(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)^2)$$

then $\dot{V}=-2V$.

---

So my method was to find $\dot V$ then equate that to $-2V$ and rearrange to find $u$. But this seems very messy, is there a nicer way to do this?

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &= x_1\dot{x}_1 + (\dot x_1 + 2x_1\dot x_1 + 3x_1^2\dot x_1 + \dot x_2)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2) \\
&= \dot x_1\big[x_1 + (1 + 2x_1+3x_1^2)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big] + \dot x_2(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2) \\
&= (x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big[x_1 + (1 + 2x_1+3x_1^2)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big] + (x_1^2+u)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2) \\
&= (x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big[x_1 + (1 + 2x_1+3x_1^2)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big] + x_1^2(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2) + u(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\\
&=-(x_1^2+(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)^2)
\end{align}

$$\iff u(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)=-(x_1^2+(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)^2)-x_1^2(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)-(x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big[x_1 + (1 + 2x_1+3x_1^2)(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\big]$$

$$\implies u=-\frac{(x_1^2+(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)^2)}{(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)}-x_1^2-(x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)\left[\frac{x_1}{(x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)} + (1 + 2x_1+3x_1^2)\right]$$

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to use any other approach. I am curious why would anyone want to do what you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly an example of **backstepping design.** This is a sequential design methodology for strict feedback nonlinear systems (note that in your example $x_2$ can be seen as an 'input' to the $x_1$ subsystem). So the idea is to select an appropriate virtual control $\alpha_1(x_1)$ that can stabilize the $x_1$ subsystem if $x_2=\alpha_1(x_1)$ and then drive the difference $z_2:=x_2-\alpha_1(x_1)$ to zero by selecting suitable $u$.

So if you select
$$\alpha_1(x_1)=-x_1^2-x_1^3-x_1$$
and define the new error variable
$$z_2:=x_2-\alpha_1(x_1)=x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2$$
then your $V$ takes the form
$$V=\frac{1}{2}x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}z_2^2$$
and 
$$\dot{x}_1=-x_1+z_2\\
\dot{z}_2=x_1^2+u-\frac{d\alpha_1}{dx_1}\dot{x}_1$$
Note now that
$$\dot{V}=x_1(-x_1+z_2)+z_2\dot{z}_2=-x_1^2+z_2(x_1+x_1^2+u-\frac{d\alpha_1}{dx_1}\dot{x}_1)$$
Thus selecting
$$u=-x_1-x_1^2+\frac{d\alpha_1}{dx_1}\dot{x}_1-z_2$$
guarantees
$$\dot{V}=-x_1^2-z_2^2=-2V$$
Hence the desired control input is
$$u=-x_1-x_1^2+(-1-2x_1-3x_1^2)(x_1^2+x_1^3+x_2)-(x_2+x_1+x_1^2+x_1^3)$$

Comment: It would be interesting to know why my answer was downvoted.